# How to close sessions (connections) to sql-database (vertica) recursively

Tags: sql, vertica

I accidently created many connections to our vertica database via JDBC driver. It's impossible to close them programmatically through my JDBC driver and the only option left is to close them with SQL query. In Vertica, I want to run

```
select close_session(select session_id from sessions  where client_hostname like '%.195%');
```

or

```
select close_session() from sessions where session_id in (select distinct session_id from sessions  where client_hostname like '%.195%');
```

Both options are wrong and don't work. What is the proper solution? 
(I can't use close_all_sessions() because that will kill ongoing queries of my colleagues. I can close 50 sessions manually but it's useful to know the right way to make this work anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first, ask yourself why are you allowing more than 50 client sessions?

I would then prepare the `CLOSE_SESSION()` statements and run them:

```
SELECT E'SELECT CLOSE_SESSION(\'' || session_id || E'\');' 
FROM   user_sessions
WHERE  client_hostname LIKE '%.195%';
```

Comment: I opened so many sessions by mistake (in the loop)
how do I run these prepared sessions? Just copy and paste?.

Comment: @RInatM Correct. Copy the output of this query into a query and run.